# Настройки Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

Доброго времени суток!

Хочу попросить помощи с настройкой Visual Studio Code которая сбросилась или которую я сам каким-то образом отключил.

В общем хочу что-бы папка с проектом была открыта вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но сейчас при открытии папки с проектом у меня она открыта в общем, но файлы приходится добавлять вручную перетаскивая их с самой папки.

Возможно я как-то не так открываю папку или ещё что-нибудь, в общем прошу помощи!